# Show a search input bar depending on which path the user currently is viewing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel with the Blade template engine. I'm trying to show a search input bar, depending on which path the user currently is viewing. The three paths are `all`, `snes` and `nes`.

This is what I have done so far:

```
@if (request()->route()->getName() === 'snes')
    @include('partials._search')
@endif

@if (request()->route()->getName() === 'nes')
    @include('partials._search')
@endif

@if (request()->route()->getName() === 'all')
    @include('partials._search')
@endif
```

It doesn't seem so effective nor like good looking code.

How can I shorten this?

Comment: Why not simply use the `@elseif` [control structure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#control-structures)?

Comment: Is there a view model for this page? What variables are available in this template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PHPs `in_array()` function to test the current route against your required routes:

```
@php ( $searchRoutes = ['foo', 'bar'] )
@if( in_array(request()->route()->getName(), $searchRoutes))
   @include('partials._search')
@endif
```

You could define the allowed routes array in your controller and pass this into the blade template.

Comment: Be careful with shorthand arrays if PHP < 5.4